# Java 8 - Save multiple object list from Kairosdb into a csv file

Tags: java, apache-spark, kairosdb

I have a requirement to create a csv file from all the metric values from Kairosdb.

The kairosdb UI already has a save as feature but it doesn't have a metric name in the exported file. Also we can't export multiple metrics into a single file.

The problem I am facing is with matching the timestamp from multiple metrics. For ex, One metric might return 5 timestamp values. Another metric might return 10 timestamp values which may be matching with previous metric or not.

So I need to generate a csv like below:

```
tmestamp,metric1,metric2,tmetric3\n
0,1,,2\n
1,,2,\n
2,1,3,6\n
3,5,5, \n
4,,,5\n
```

The value returned from the query might be more than 10000 datapoints. How can I approach this problem. Can I run this program in spark cluster.

The code that I tried:

```
package com.example;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.kairosdb.client.builder.DataPoint;
public class Test {
private static Map<MetricMap, String> metricMaps = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<String, List<DataPoint>> metriDps = new HashMap<>();
    String[] metricNames = new String[] { "m1", "m2", "m3" };
    List<DataPoint> dataPoints1 = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(0, 1);
    DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(2, 1);
    DataPoint dp3 = new DataPoint(3, 5);
    dataPoints1.add(dp1);
    dataPoints1.add(dp2);
    dataPoints1.add(dp3);
    metriDps.put("m1", dataPoints1);
    List<DataPoint> dataPoints2 = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    DataPoint dp21 = new DataPoint(1, 2);
    DataPoint dp22 = new DataPoint(2, 3);
    DataPoint dp23 = new DataPoint(3, 5);
    dataPoints2.add(dp21);
    dataPoints2.add(dp22);
    dataPoints2.add(dp23);
    metriDps.put("m2", dataPoints2);
    List<DataPoint> dataPoints3 = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    DataPoint dp31 = new DataPoint(0, 2);
    DataPoint dp32 = new DataPoint(2, 6);
    DataPoint dp33 = new DataPoint(4, 5);
    dataPoints3.add(dp31);
    dataPoints3.add(dp32);
    dataPoints3.add(dp33);
    metriDps.put("m3", dataPoints3);
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/home/lr/Desktop/csv1.csv");
        metriDps.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> createMap(metriDps.get(key), key));
        String value;
        for (MetricMap metricMap : metricMaps.keySet()) {
            String time = metricMap.getTime();
            writer.append(time);
            writer.append(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                MetricMap map = new MetricMap();
                map.setName(metricNames[i]);
                map.setTime(time);
                value = metricMaps.get(map);
                if (value != null)
                    writer.append(metricMaps.get(map));
                else 
                    writer.append("");
                if (i == 2)
                    writer.append('\n');
                else
                    writer.append(',');
            }
        }
        // generate whatever data you want

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void createMap(List<DataPoint> list, String key) {

    MetricMap map = null;

    for (DataPoint dp : list) {
        map = new MetricMap();
        map.setName(key);
        map.setTime(String.valueOf(dp.getTimestamp()));
        metricMaps.put(map, String.valueOf(dp.getValue()));
    }

}
```

}

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: series are ordered by time? I would use that to iterate all 3 "in parallel", building the output on the go. Storing everything in a map first uses way more memory than necessary which could restrict scalability (you can probably query all 3 with a smaller time slice to reduce the batch size you have to deal with)

Comment: Yes series are ordered by time. Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: The code that I have is writing duplicate values to a csv file. I am struck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your algorithm work, you'll have to map that has time as key, and point's value + metric names as value. The following does that:

```
Map<String, List<DataPoint>> metriDps = new HashMap<>();
String[] metricNames = new String[] {
        "m1", "m2", "m3"
};
List<DataPoint> dataPoints1 = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
dataPoints1.add(new DataPoint(0, 1));
dataPoints1.add(new DataPoint(2, 1));
dataPoints1.add(new DataPoint(3, 5));
metriDps.put("m1", dataPoints1);

List<DataPoint> dataPoints2 = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
dataPoints2.add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
dataPoints2.add(new DataPoint(2, 3));
dataPoints2.add(new DataPoint(3, 5));
metriDps.put("m2", dataPoints2);

List<DataPoint> dataPoints3 = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
dataPoints3.add(new DataPoint(0, 2));
dataPoints3.add(new DataPoint(2, 6));
dataPoints3.add(new DataPoint(4, 5));
metriDps.put("m3", dataPoints3);

SortedMap<Long, Map<String, String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
// format:
// time1 -> [(metricName, value), (metricName, value), ..]
// time2 -> [(metricName, value), (metricName, value), ..]
// ..

metriDps.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(entry -> {
            List<DataPoint> points = entry.getValue();
            String metric = entry.getKey();
            points.forEach(point -> {
                Long time = point.getTimestamp();
                Object value = point.getValue();
                if (value != null)
                    // add (metricName, value) to map stored under time
                    map.computeIfAbsent(time, key -> new HashMap<>())
                            .put(metric, value.toString());
            });
        });

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
// header
writer.append("timestamp,");
writer.append(Stream.of(metricNames).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
writer.append('\n');
// content, sorted map means we can simply iterate it's keys
map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
    // time
    writer.append(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));
    writer.append(',');
    // fetch all possible metric names from the map so it prints empty ",,"
    String line = Stream.of(metricNames)
            .map(entry.getValue()::get)
            .map(val -> val == null ? "" : val)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    writer.append(line);
    writer.append('\n');
});
System.out.println(writer);
```

Prints

```
timestamp,m1,m2,m3
0,1,,2
1,,2,
2,1,3,6
3,5,5,
4,,,5
```

With sorted input lists, you can improve the algorithm by keeping 3 iterators, then advancing the one(s) that point to the earliest value. You can thereby iterate all series in parallel / side-by-side. That way you can save some memory because you don't have to build maps and process the lists one by one.

---

Using the following utility class

```
static class NamedKeeparator implements Iterator<DataPoint> {
    private final Iterator<DataPoint> delegate;
    private final String name;
    private DataPoint                 current;

    public NamedKeeparator(String name, Iterator<DataPoint> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return delegate.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public DataPoint next() {
        return current = delegate.next();
    }

    public DataPoint current() {
        return current;
    }

    public void consume() {
        current = null;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

A potential implementation could be

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
// header
writer.append("timestamp,");
writer.append(Stream.of(metricNames).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
writer.append('\n');

List<NamedKeeparator> iterators = metriDps.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new NamedKeeparator(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().iterator()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<NamedKeeparator> leastIterators = new ArrayList<>();
for (;;) {
    leastIterators.clear();
    long leastValue = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for (NamedKeeparator iterator : iterators) {
        // advance until there is some value
        while (iterator.current() == null && iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
        }
        // build set of iterators pointing to least value
        if (iterator.current() != null
                && iterator.current().getTimestamp() <= leastValue) {
            if (iterator.current().getTimestamp() < leastValue) {
                leastValue = iterator.current().getTimestamp();
                leastIterators.clear();
            }
            leastIterators.add(iterator);
        }
    }
    // nothing -> all iterators done
    if (leastIterators.isEmpty())
        break;

    // least contains now iterators for the same timestamp

    // get time from the first
    long time = leastIterators.get(0).current().getTimestamp();
    writer.append(String.valueOf(time)).append(',');

    // format points
    String points = Stream.of(metricNames)
            .map(metric -> leastIterators.stream()
                    .filter(it -> it.getName().equals(metric)).findAny()
                    .map(it -> it.current()).orElse(null))
            .map(point -> point != null ? String.valueOf(point.getValue()) : "")
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    writer.append(points).append('\n');

    leastIterators.forEach(it -> {
        it.consume();
    });
}
System.out.println(writer);
```

http://ideone.com/pVCfNB